# How to generate html report for TestNG test cases run in Netbeans?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, reporting, netbeans-8

How to generate the test-output folder for a testNG test?

I am trying to get the default testng report, index.html

Netbeans7/windows7

I made a simple testng test case, ran it in netbeans 7, and here is the result.  I see no test-output.  I am displaying the project and file structure.

If I need to do something with ant or maven, please describe VERY detailed steps as to how to proceed on Windows 7 -- I am new to both of those tools.

If I need to do something with build.xml, please give explicit, detailed steps

[image: netbeans testng output and project file structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective of IDE, TestNG should generate a file, **index.html** in "**test-output**" folder, that is default html report from TestNG. These default reports can be disabled by setting property `useDefaultListeners` to `false` in your build tools ( Ant or Maven ). Are you not able to locate this index.html in NetBeans or are you looking for some other reports? I am not sure if your question meant to say something specific about **NetBeans IDE**.

Comment: I have not used TestNG with NetBeans but this link describes it well [NetBeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/TestNG). You do need Maven or Ant though.

Answer (score 3):

TestNG generate an HTML output itself, you can check `test-out > index.html` location in your project.